# Have one device communicate to another with the same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, messaging

Im pretty new to iOS development, so I don't really have an idea of where to start with my question. Im wondering how I might go about sending a message to another device with the same application installed? Basically Im looking to have the application send a message from Device 1 (the device requesting information) to Device 2, (the device that has the information that Device 1 needs) and have Device 2 respond with the correct information.

A more "real" example... The user of Device 1 wants to know the "favorite number" value that the user of Device 2 has saved in the app. I am looking to send some sort of request for Device 2's favorite number, and have Device 2 be able to send it back to Device 1.

Im not sure how this would be completed. Any information that you gan provide - instructions, examples, etc. - would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Are these two random devices on the Internet or are both always nearby physically or on the same WiFi network?

Comment: @rmaddy Both devices would be connected to the internet via WiFi or cellular network. The proximity of the devices could vary from close (in the same room), or very far away (10s or 100s of milea apart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will have a lots of solution:

1. you can Create a web serice, to finfish the message sending job.
2. or you can try [Parse](https://parse.com/) , and [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) is also greate!

PS:solution 2 also need some server programming, and pusher is way more easier.

Comment: could you please explain a little more? How would I implement the services in option 2 into my app?